# How to set up multiple wordpress sites on linux correctly?

Tags: linux, wordpress

I have setup a linode to host few client's WordPress sites.

I added all sites to

```
var/www/html/site1.com/public_html<br>
var/www/html/site2.com/public_html<br>
var/www/html/site3.com/public_html<br>
```

and gave the www-data user permission:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html<br>
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/site2.com/public_html<br>
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/site3.com/public_html<br>
```

Now issue is PHP is able to write across all those folders which means if one site gets compromised , hacker will be able to access other sites public_html via PHP.

What is the best secure way to set this up ?
Step by step guide will help !! Thank you so much.

Comment: Which web server are you using? Apache? Nginx? If you're using Apache, for example, look into VirtualHosts.

Comment: Using Apache Server. Each website has its own .conf file

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate user for each website like site1, site2, site3
Then assign user and group for each website to get your expected security.

```
sudo chown -R site1:site1 /var/www/html/site1.com/public_html
sudo chown -R site2:site2 /var/www/html/site2.com/public_html
sudo chown -R site3:site3 /var/www/html/site3.com/public_html
```

Add user to www-data group so that you wordpreess can run regular operations such as update, delete, install...

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data site1
sudo usermod -a -G www-data site3
sudo usermod -a -G www-data site3
```

Comment: How do they become www-data users then ?

Comment: why do you need www-data ?
www-data is the user that web servers on Ubuntu (Apache, nginx, for example) use by default for normal operation. 
When you are assigning site1 as the owner&group of the files of site1.com, that site will get it's required permissions to do it's job.

Comment: I came to know wordpress needs www-data for updating and installing plugins, core udpates etc..

Comment: Well, just add site1, site, site3 in www-data group
I have updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I did the other way around - add www-data to the user group. And change the permissions to 775, 664. Is it safe ?

Comment: You did the opposite, I don't think you will get the expected result.
And WordPress recommended directory and files permission are 755, 644 respectfully.

Comment: If I add user to www-data, then i need to change file / folder group owner to www-data right ? In that case also, the users will be able to modify each others directory. Any solution ?